# How to set Textview height between two imageview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, imageview

I have a `TextView` to display order items and quantity. But it overlaps with the divider lines above and below. How to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18VcnYN5_LM !-->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:animationCache="true"
    android:gravity="center|start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp">


    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/grey600"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.skydoves.androidribbon.RibbonView
                android:id="@+id/order_status_ribbon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
                android:letterSpacing=".10"
                android:text="@string/order_status"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                app:ribbon_background_color="@color/primaryYellow"
                app:ribbon_padding_top="4dp"
                app:ribbon_ribbonRadius="4dp"
                app:textAllCaps="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                android:text="@string/sample_order_id"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/order_status_ribbon" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_date_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                android:text="@string/date_amp_time"
                android:textColor="@color/grey600"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/order_id" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dotted_line_order_after_date_time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layerType="software"
                android:src="@drawable/dotted"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/order_date_time"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_items"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                android:text="@string/order_items_and_quantity"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dotted_line_order"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dotted_line_order_after_date_time"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.418" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dotted_line_order"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:layerType="software"
                android:src="@drawable/dotted"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/order_date_time"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/view_details"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dotted_line_order"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Sample image is found in https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg6Mq.jpg

As you can see in the image the **order items and quantity**  `TextView` is overlapping with `ImageView`. The text for `TextView` comes from a StringBuffer

```
 sb.append(n.getInt("quantiy"));
 sb.append(" X ");
 sb.append(n.getString("name"));
 sb.append("\n");
 holder.orderItems.setText(sb);
```

Comment: Could you please add expected image?

Comment: Try [this out](https://pastebin.com/6ANvLuZz)

Answer (score 0):

The `dotted_line_order` ImageView constrained to `order_date_time` TextView Using `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/order_date_time"`.

While the overlapped `order_items` TextView constrained to `dotted_line_order` ImageView with `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dotted_line_order"`.

Both constraints will make the `order_items` overlaps with the `dotted_line_order`.

You need to replace the 1st constraint to be constrained to the `order_items` instead of the `order_date_time`, so it should be `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/order_items"`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dotted_line_order"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layerType="software"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/order_items" 
    android:src="@drawable/dotted" />
```

Also, check if 80dp margin as it seems some how big.